# ColdFusion session timing out too early

Tags: session, coldfusion, timeout, session-timeout

I have ColdFusion 10 installed as our main server. I am using sessions to store some information and have set `sessiontimeout=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,45,0)#` in the application file but for some reason the session is timing out way before 45 mins - around 10 mins. Is there a reason for this? I thought having the timeout in the application file would overwrite anything set in the ColdFusion admin. Is this not true?

Comment: Can you put some code into `onRequestEnd()` & `onSessionEnd()` for enable you to be more accurate as to how long it's taking a session time timeout? And is it *all* sessions?

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: "[Configuring and using session variables](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Configuring+and+using+session+variables)":

> You can also set the time-out period for session variables inside a
>   specific application (thereby overruling the Administrator default
>   setting) by setting the Application.cfc This.sessionTimeout variable
>   or by using the cfapplication tag sessionTimeout attribute. **However,
>   you cannot set a time-out value for that is greater than the maximum
>   session time-out value set on the Administrator Memory Variables page**.

My **emphasis**.

Could this be your issue? You don't tell us what your CFAdmin settings actually are.

Comment: That's the one I was looking for... sheesh.

Comment: its possible the admin isnt set up properly but under 'server setting's > 'memory variables' the session variables 'default timeout' is set to 45minutes... but under 'session cookie settings' the 'cookie timeout' option is set to 20mins - could that be problem?

Comment: Well given the *default* is **thirty years**, I would say having that set in a granularity of minutes is probably wrong. And, yes, it also means your cookies - needed to associate the browser with a session - expire before your session does. Which will orphan the sessions. Now... you said your sessions are timing out... do you mean the sessions on the SERVER are timing out, or the association between the browser cookie and the server session is being lost? Those are two different things. Which is it?

Comment: Ref for that 30yrs thing: https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Security+enhancements+in+ColdFusion+10. You did read those docs, right? You're not just staring at the screen wondering how things work without actually... trying to find out for yourself. Right?

Comment: Its the associaition between the browser and the server i.e. browser is asking me to log in. Looked at links but possible i'm not doing it correct as i'm using an application.cfm page rather than an application.cfc (never set that up before).

This is the code I am using in the application.cfm file:

<cfapplication name="SYOP" sessionmanagement="yes" setclientcookies="yes" sessiontimeout=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,45,0)#/>

I set the cookie timeout to be 45 minutes and its not timing out after the 10 - 20 mins but after the 45 minutes it logs me out of the site even if I am actually using the site.

Comment: Just leave the cookie alone. You don't want to force a timeout on it. Let CF manage that. And if poss move on from `Application.cfm`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things come to mind.

You have it backwards. The CF admin allows you to set a specific maximum value that overrides application specific values IF the application specific values exceed the maximum. See this link:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ff4

It references Application variable timeouts and is mute on sessions but the behavior should be the same. I'm sure other CF folks can correct me if I'm wrong about this.

So, I would check the settings in the CF Administrator (under memory variables). The "maximum" time set for sessions there will be in play if it is less than 45 minutes.  I believe the default is 2 hours, but if someone set it to, say 10 minutes, then that could be your issue.

A session is tied to the Application itself. If you are changing the application name (for example) it wipes out all the sessions - or rather, they still exist but under the "old" application name which is not accessible.

Remember that restarting CF will wipe out sessions.

Sessions are server/memory specific. If you have multiple servers then switching from server A to server B will cause the user to lose his session. There are strategies to avoid this (sticky sessions, clustering and replication etc).

A session can be programmatically removed. You would probably know if that was the case but it is worth making note of.

those are all the things I can think of. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the syntax in the cfset statement should not have ## in it, the way I do it is something like this:

```
<cfset this.applicationTimeout= createtimespan(0,0,45,0)>
```